# I am trying to find the distance of a node from the root of a binary tree

Tags: c++17, binary-tree

I am trying to find the distance of a node from the root of a binary tree but I am getting right answer up to only 3 branches only. like for the node(4) I am getting 3 and for the node  (9) and node(10) I am getting 3

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    node(int val)
    {
        data = val;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
};

int find_node(node* root,int n)
{
   static int length=1;
    if (root== NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (root->data==n)
    {
    return length; 
    }
    length=length+(find_node(root->left,n)||find_node(root->right,n));
    // find_node(root->left,n);
    // find_node(root->right,n);
    return length;

}

int main ()
{
    struct node* root = new node(1);
    root->left = new node(2);
    root->right = new node(3);
    root->left->left = new node(4);
    root->left->right = new node(5);
    root->right->left = new node(6);
    root->right->right = new node(7);
    root->right->right->right = new node(9);
    root->right->right->right->right = new node(10);
    cout <<find_node(root,10);

return 0;}
```

Comment: If `find_node(root->left,n)` returns non-zero, `find_node(root->right,n)` is not called, since logical-or `||` operator short-circuits. And `find_node` returns non-zero even when it doesn't find anything. I think your program computes the length of the path from root to left-most leaf, the path that only follows `left` links.

Answer (score 0):

When your code reaches the first leaf node (with data 4), the following assignment will assign 1:

```
length=length+(find_node(root->left,n)||find_node(root->right,n));
```

Because the expression resolves to `1+(0||0)`, i.e. 1. And so 1 is returned.

The caller (at the node with data 2) will thus receive this 1, and so the above statement will yield 2, since it resolves to `1+(1||......)`, which is 2 -- the second operand of `||` is not evaluated.

The parent caller (at the node with data 1), will thus receive this 2. The assignment there resolves to `1+(2||.....)`, which is again 2 -- realise that `||` is a logical operator, so it can only evaluate to a boolean value (i.e. 0 or 1).

#### The issues

In summmary:

- You should not use `||` as it can only evaluate to 0 or 1, losing the actual value from recursion that you need.
- You should not use a `static` variable. For one, it would not reset if you would make a second call to this function from the main program code. Instead, every recursive call should just "mind its own business" and return the depth of `n` from the given `root`. The caller should add 1 to that if `n` was found.

#### Correction

```
int find_node(node* root, int n)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (root->data == n)
    {
        return 1; 
    }
    int length = find_node(root->left, n);
    if (!length)
    {
        length = find_node(root->right, n);
    }
    if (!length)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + length;
}
```

Comment: sir after I review the code and replaced it with your code I am still getting the same answer which I was getting in my function

Comment: I just tried it again, and your code outputs 2. After replacing the function with my version, it outputs 3. See the code after I the replaced function on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomq708194635459839). Run it, and see output 3.

Comment: sir please try your function for nodes like (9 and 10) you will get output 3 for all nodes like (7,9,10)

Comment: Corrected. Also when the second recursive call returns 0, a return of 0 should happen.